How are these answers derived (Flip-Flops)?

From my understanding, the truth table for J/k Flip-flops are:
j  k  Q(T+1)
0  0  Q(t)
0  1  0
1  0  1
1  1  Q'(t)

The next state of A [ A(t+1) ] is the output of the j/k flip flop.
The input to this j/k flip flop is the result of the top AND gate.
The top AND gate takes X and A as inputs and outputs AX.
So for
A  B  x  XA  J = XA  K = XA  A(t+1) = JK
0  0  0  0   0       0       Q(t)

But the answers says it should be 0 for these values of A and X. Where is my confusion coming from?

Q(t) is the current A, which is 0. Aside, note, that the JK circuit is essentially in a T-flipflop configuration. That might simplify the analysis.

Facepalm just replace Q(t) with the state of A. Thanks!

But the answer below is rightfully pointing out the actual problem with the question.

The answer is wrong (inverted).

When A(t) = 0, A(t+1) = 0

When A(t) = 1:
A(t+1) = 1 if X = 0

A(t+1) = 0 if X = 1




So essentially, given the initial condition of A=0, it can never reach the state where A=1

I'm sorry, just to be clear. The truth table for A)t+1) is as follows
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
is this correct?

Sorry, I meant.
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0

I analyzed the sequential network based on the characteristic equations of the FFs which, modified by the network configurations, provide the individual outputs:

